# Setup Iot Edge Simulator issue when we are giving iot edge connection string

Tags: visual-studio-2019, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-hub-device-management

We created sample iot edge application using visual studio 2019. When we are trying to setup iot edge device connection string in Setup Iot Edge Simulator getting below error.

> C:\Users\10070047\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\iotedgehubdev\v0.14.2\iotedgehubdev setup -c HostName={connection string}
> [16472] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py", line 11, in 
> File "d:\a\1\s\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
> File "lib\site-packages\pkg_resources_*init*_.py", line 86, in 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources.py2_warn'
> [ERROR]: Failed to run 'iotedgehubdev setup -c HostName={connectionstring}' with error: [16472] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py", line 11, in 
> File "d:\a\1\s\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
> File "lib\site-packages\pkg_resources_*init*_.py", line 86, in 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources.py2_warn'

FYI. tried with setup the connection string
[image]

Can someone please help me on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few days ago an update to the Azure IoT Edge Tools for Visual Studio introduced this bug. It worked fine in 1.6, but is broken in 1.7.
It has been reported on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-azure-iot-edge-docs/issues/28#issuecomment-712730479) and the Microsoft [Q&A forums](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/132170/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-39pkg-resource.html). Both platforms usually resolve these errors quickly, so keep a look out!

Update: [A workaround](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-azure-iot-edge-docs/issues/28#issuecomment-712765723) was posted in lieu of an official fix.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with 0.14.2 version of iotedgehubdev, I tried to downgrade it with 0.14.1, but could not downgrade it. But what we did, Replaced the contents of " C:\Users***\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\iotedgehubdev\v0.14.2" with "iotedgehubdev\v0.14.1". Then it worked.

[iotedgehubdev-v0.14.1](https://github.com/Azure/iotedgehubdev/releases/tag/v0.14.1)

[GitHub - workaround posted by chull434](https://github.com/Azure/iotedgehubdev/issues/288#issuecomment-711150029)